# MacOS CI Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

When attempting to run an archive of a MacOS Catalyst app, the codesigning fails as the machines the service is using aren't registered to my Device Portal at : [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com).

As `MacOS` apps are archived against `My Mac` and not a `Generic iOS Device` how does this codesigning process work when running a remote CI build.

I'm currently getting this error from the archive `Provisioning profile "Mac Catalyst Team Provisioning Profile: ******" doesn't include the currently selected device`

**Any help would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: You'll probably have to add the certificates to the keychain of the build machine

Comment: The certificate is already in the keychain of the build machine...thats one of the build steps prior to archiving